# add swipe gesture to linear layout to swip menu like facebook android

Tags: java, android, performance, swipe-gesture

how can make swipe gesture to linear layout to swipe menu like Facebook app in android 
smoothly, fast animation.

i'm using fragments.

i need to add swipe this menu like Facebook app.

Comment: u can use SimonVT's menu drawer library [menudrawer](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer/tree/master/menudrawer-samples/src/net/simonvt/menudrawer/samples) for that.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems like you need sliding menu. you can find a library which does that for you [here](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/)